# Jquery Return text toggle

Tags: jquery

I was looking to alter the code below and have a div that says "unsubscribe" in the html show up in the toggle and not have that part controlled by text in the js. So ideally I'd like to remove " return txt === "Unsubscribe" ? "Subscribe" : "Unsubscribe";" and just have the divs toggle. Any ideas?

Comment: you are already using the toggle() function.. why not just use it? (make another div and toggle between them)

Comment: that was not the way I would like it to function. The subscribe should not be visible when clicked and unsubscribe should be the link with .myclass that take you back when clicked to submit.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the structure (jsfiddle is not working for me... so i didn't test it.)

```
<div>
    <a class="subscribe">subscribe</a>
    <p style="display:none;">success subscribe <a class="back">link back</a></p>
    <p style="display:none;">successful unsubscribe</p>
</div>

$(".subscribe").click(function(){
      $(this).hide();  // hide line one
      $(this).next().show();  // show line two
});

$(".back").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();  // hide line two
    $(this).parent().prev().show();  // show line one
    $(this).parent().next().show();  // show line three

});
```

Comment: changing the structure isn't an option

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you could potentially do this with the help of css:

[very slow fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8M8w/27/)

#### html

```
<div class='subscribe'> 
    <div id='divB' style="display:none">You are now Subscribed</div> 
    <a href='#' class='toggleSubscribe'></a>
</div>
```

#### css

```
.toggleSubscribe:before { content:"Subscribe";}
.myClass:before { content:"Unsubscribe";}
```

#### js

```
$('a.toggleSubscribe').click(function() {
    $("#divB").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('myClass');
});
```

Comment: this script in invalid. It doesn't allow me to add multiple instances of it on one page. And the goal is to use the divs to toggle and eliminate it from the js. I would prefer it does not get added to the css either.

Comment: Ok. first, you could definitely use this technique with multiple instances with a few tweaks.. second, please explain the logic of using a toggled div only..? I don't see the benefit.. third, why not use css?